# Make git less strict on 'similar commands', more trigger happy autocorrect?

Tags: git

I use `help.autocorrect` in my git config file in order to automatically correct, for example, `git pulk` to `git pull`:

```
$ git pulk
WARNING: You called a Git command named 'pulk', which does not exist.
Continuing in 0.1 seconds, assuming that you meant 'pull'.
Current branch master is up to date
```

However, if my typo was instead `pul`:

```
$ git pul
git: 'pul' is not a git command. See 'git --help'.

The most similar commands are
    pull
    push
```

There's no way that if I typed `l` I meant `sh`, it's the opposite side of the keyboard.

(This specific example catches me out frequently - so I could, perhaps should, just add `alias.pul = pull` to my config, but there are others too.)

Is there any way - through configuration - to modify 'similar commands' detection, or the maximum distance from a valid command that triggers autocorrection?

Comment: I think git does not care about the distance of the letters on the keyboard...

Comment: @dan1st Evidently, but I do. And to be clear, when I say 'maximum distance from a valid command', I mean the Levenshtein distance, or whatever measure is being used for 'similar commands'.

Comment: yes, but 2 is a pretty small Levenshtein distance too... I don't think you can fix that easily...

Comment: BTW, if you do want to take "key distance" into account, remember that there are different languages with different keyboards. On a French keyboard, A and Z are adjacent on the top row, replacing Q and W on a US/UK keyboard, for instance.

Comment: Oh for sure, I wasn't really suggesting that git should do that; just the reason for my frustration in this case - because I know *I* (with my keyboard) will never mean `push` when I type `pul`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's [hardcoded in the Git front end](https://github.com/git/git/blob/2d2118b814c11f509e1aa76cb07110f7231668dc/help.c#L620-L693) (and yes, it uses a Levenshtein distance calculation).  Git looks at all the "common" commands that are "similar enough".  If there is only *one* such command, Git uses it when you've selected autocorrect.  Otherwise, regardless of whether you selected autocorrect, Git will simply list all the commands it found that are "similar enough".

If you want different behavior:

- clone the Git project;
- change the source code; and
- build and install your version.

Answer (score -1):

If you are using that setting in a *bare* repository, make sure to use Git 2.40+.
Meaning, even with the current "similar command" detection, it might still not work (before Git 2.40).

The code to auto-correct a miss-pelt sub-command unnecessarily called into `git_default_config()` from the early config code-path, which was a no-no.
This has bee corrected with Git 2.40 (Q1 2023).

See [commit 0918d08](https://github.com/git/git/commit/0918d0888767d42a7232b110f5ec510945256b7e) (29 Oct 2022) by [Simon Gerber (`simu`)](https://github.com/simu).
<sup>(Merged by [Junio C Hamano -- `gitster` --](https://github.com/gitster) in [commit 4a9b839](https://github.com/git/git/commit/4a9b839dd1166b3f205ff77e9f3ebdedb045ccba), 26 Dec 2022)</sup>

> ### [`help.c`](https://github.com/git/git/commit/0918d0888767d42a7232b110f5ec510945256b7e): fix autocorrect in work tree for bare repository
>
> <sup>Signed-off-by: Simon Gerber</sup>

> Currently, auto correction doesn't work reliably for commands which must run in a work tree (e.g. [`git status`](https://github.com/git/git/blob/0918d0888767d42a7232b110f5ec510945256b7e/Documentation/git-status.txt)<sup>([man](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-status))</sup>) in Git work trees which are created from a bare repository.
>
> As far as I'm able to determine, this has been broken since [commit 659fef1](https://github.com/git/git/commit/659fef199fb52d4a5cb24f1dfd2b272980fc5038) ("`help`: use early config when autocorrecting aliases", 2017-06-14, Git v2.14.0-rc0 -- [merge](https://github.com/git/git/commit/1c3d87cf5594cc7e57d71c7b2d99dd4982285951) listed in [batch #11](https://github.com/git/git/commit/a2ba37c57b7e1f72900b0c1183ef38e52c3f9d27)), where the call to `git_config()` in `help_unknown_cmd()` was replaced with a call to `read_early_config()`.
> From what I can tell, the actual cause for the unexpected error is that we call `git_default_config()` in the `git_unknown_cmd_config` callback instead of simply returning `0` for config entries which we aren't interested in.
>
> Calling `git_default_config()` in this callback to `read_early_config()` seems like a bad idea since those calls will initialize a bunch of state in [`environment.c`](https://github.com/git/git/blob/0918d0888767d42a7232b110f5ec510945256b7e/environment.c) (among other things `is_bare_repository_cfg`) before we've properly detected that we're running in a work tree.
>
> All other callbacks provided to `read_early_config()` appear to only extract their configurations while simply returning `0` for all other config keys.
>
> This commit changes the `git_unknown_cmd_config` callback to not call `git_default_config()`.
> Instead we also simply return `0` for config keys which we're not interested in.
>
> Additionally the commit adds a new test case covering `help.autocorrect` in a work tree created from a bare clone.

So this should work more reliably now:

```bash
test_expect_success 'autocorrect works in work tree created from bare repo' '
    git clone --bare . bare.git &&
    git -C bare.git worktree add ../worktree &&
    git -C worktree -c help.autocorrect=immediate stauts
```